# React JS Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm newbie to React JS. was following a tutorial for developing portfolio by react js.
End up at error after running npm start command.
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `App`.
▼ 21 stack frames were expanded.

[Error on page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vGyR.png)
[[Error on page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92wIj.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2V90a.png)

heres index.js

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import './index.css'
import App from './App'

ReactDOM.render(<App/>,document.querySelector("#root"));
```

heres index.css

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;400;500;600&display=swap');

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border :0;
  outline: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}
:root {
  --color-bg:#e0fbfc;
  --color-bg-variant: #f3d0a5;
  --color-primary : #22497f;
  --color-primary-variant: rgba(77,181,255,0.4);
  --color-font : #203d66;
  --color-light: #f2a95b;

  --transition : all 400ms ease;

  --container-width-lg:75%;
  --container-width-md:86%;
  --container-width-sm:90%;
}

html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: _none;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  background: var(--color-bg);
  color: var(--color-font);
  line-height: 1.7;
  /*background-image: url(../src/assests/background.jpg);*/
}
/*=================General style==================*/

.container {
  width: var(--container-width-lg);
  margin : 0 auto;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5 {
  font-weight: 500;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}

section {
  margin-top: 8rem;
  height: 100vh;
}

section > h2, section > h5 {
  text-align: center;
  color: var(--color-light);
}

section > h2 {
  color: var(--color-primary);
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
}

.text.light {
  color : var(--color-light);
}

a {
  color: var(--color-primary);
  transition: var(--transition);
}

a:hover {
  color: var(--color-font);
}

.btn {
  width: max-content;
  display: inline-block;
  color: var(--color-primary);
  padding: 0.75rem 1.2rem;
  border-radius: 0.4rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid var(--color-primary);
  transition: var(--transition);

}

.btn:hover {
  background : var(--color-font);
  color : vafr(var(--color-bg));
  border-color: transparent;
}

.btn-primary {
  background: var(--color-primary);
  color: var(--color-bg);

}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

/*=======================Media queries (medium device)======================*/
@media  screen and (max-width : 1024px) {
  .container{
    width: var(--container-width-md);
  }
  section {
    margin-top: 6rem;
  }
}

/*=======================Media queries (small device)======================*/
@media  screen and (max-width : 600px) {
  .container{
    width: var(--container-width-sm);
  }
  section > h2 {
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
  }
}
```

heres app.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import Header from './component/header/header.jsx'
import Nav from './component/nav/nav.jsx'
import About from './component/about/about.jsx'
import Qua from './component/qualification/qualification.jsx'
import Exp from './component/experience/experience.jsx'
import Skill from './component/skillset/skillset.jsx'
import Pro from './component/project/project.jsx'
import Extra from './component/extra/extra.jsx'
import Cert from './component/certificate/certificate.jsx'
import Org from './component/organization/organization.jsx'
import Lang from './component/langauge/language.jsx'
import Contact from './component/contact/contact.jsx'
import Footer from './component/footer/footer.jsx'

const App = () =>{
  return(
    <>
      <Header />
      <Nav />
      <About />
      <Qua />
      <Exp />
      <Skill />
      <Pro />
      <Extra />
      <Cert/>
      <Org/>
      <Lang/>
      <Contact/>
      <Footer/>
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

how to solve this error

Comment: can we see a screenshot of you project structure, like the component folder and src. Plus make sure that all the files are exported as default

Comment: There is an issue with *at least* one of the components imported in `App`. Double check that all the default imported components are being default exported. If there are any issues in any of *those* components then their export will fail, so you may need to drill down until you find the suspect code. Comment out all the components rendered in `App` and uncomment one-at-a-time until it breaks, then repeat the process in *that* component until you find the cause of the issue.